# Call helper Method by Ajax Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, render

I need to update some data of my rails model without reload the page (AJAX).

I have a reputation system like http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system?autoplay=true

In my controller have this method:

```
def vote
   value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
   @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
   @idea.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
   redirect_to :back, notice: "Thank you for voting!"

end
```

In my view have this:

```
<% if current_user && !current_user.voted_for?(idea) %>
| <%= link_to "LoV", vote_idea_path(idea, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to update the following data without reload the page, In my application layout file have this:

```
strong>(<%= current_user.reputation_value_for(:votes).to_i %>).</strong>
<strong>LoV's(<%= link_to current_user.evaluations.count, user_path(current_user)%>)</strong>
```

How can I render that method "vote" with AJAX?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Setup a simple javascript:

**vote-ajax.js.coffee**

```
$("a.vote").on
    click: (event) ->
        link = $(event.target)
        $.ajax
            type:     "POST"
            url:      "/votes"
            dataType: "json"
            data:
                voteType: link.attr("data-type")
                userId:   link.attr("data-userId")

            success: (response) ->
                link.addClass("voted-#{link.attr("data-type")}")

         event.preventDefault()
         false
```

**votes_controller.rb**

```
respond_to :json

def create
  @vote = Vote.new(direction: params[:voteType], user_id: params[:userId])
  @vote.save
  respond_with @vote
end
```

That's not a complete example, nor is it tested, and you'll need to do some tweaking, but that should get you started on the right path.

You can also use

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", votes_path(direction: "up"), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

You'll need to make a `create.js.erb` file in your `views/votes` folder to handle the response, which should basically just look like the `success` callback in the method above.

Personally, I prefer the manual method (using jQuery's `ajax`) because it provides more control, and is unlikely the change in the near future, whereas Rails' UJS implementation is more likely to change. It also gives you a change to write some simple coffeescript, which is always a bonus!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I don't have a votes_controller, the vote method is inside my Idea Controller, so how can I handle that method with an Ajax request?

Comment: This answer doesn't really establish anything... you're referring to a controller in your answer, when the question clearly was addressing rails helper methods.

Comment: @cereallarceny Where's your answer?

Comment: Nonexistent, I too am looking for a proper answer.